# Can't trancate excel file in SQL SERVER 2014 import wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, c#-4.0

I have an excel file with 11000 + data that I want to upload to sql server 2014. I have created a table that I want to upload the excel file to but during the importing of the data, I can't truncate the data to varchar 50. it convert the data to nvarchar 255 and my data is not more that 50.

Later, I import the data like that and I connect it to my c# program. When I try to save client data to the database, it display

```
String or data in to be ## 

----------
 ##truncated"
```

And gain when I retrieve data from database to textbox and I updated the data, it display Conversion failed when converting date and **

I have tried to change nvarchar 255 to nvarchar max but am still having the same problem and I need to submit the project very soon.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Datadb VALUES(@CAPTURE, @SURNAME, @OTHER_NAME, @BANK, @BVN_NO, @ACCOUNT_NO, @SEX, @MOBILE_NO, @DATE_OF_RETIREMENT, @ID_CARD_NO, @PAYROLL_NO, @LEGA_LOCAL_GOVT, @YEARLY_GROSS_PAY, @MONTHLY_GROSS_PAY, @CATEGORY, @LAST_PLACE_OF_ASSIGNMENT, @FINGERPRINT)", con);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
cAPTUREPictureBox.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg byte[] CAPTURE = stream.ToArray();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAPTURE", CAPTURE);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SURNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sURNAMETextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = oTHER_NAMESTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BANK", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bANKTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BVN_NO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bVNTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACCOUNT_NO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aCCOUNT_NOTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SEX", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sEXComboBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MOBILE_NO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mOBILE_NOTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE_OF_RETIREMENT", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dATE_OF_RETIREMENTDateTimePicker.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_CARD_NO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = iD_CARD_NOTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAYROLL_NO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pAYROLL_NOTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LEGA_LOCAL_GOVT", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lEGA_LOCAL_GOVTComboBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@YEARLY_GROSS_PAY", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = yEARLY_GROSS_PAYTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MONTHLY_GROSS_PAY", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mONTHLY_GROSS_PAYTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CATEGORY", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cATEGORYComboBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LAST_PLACE_OF_ASSIGNMENT", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lAST_PLACE_OF_ASSIGNMENTTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FINGERPRINT", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Client Data Saved Successfully");
```

- When I try to save data, it display String or data need to be truncated.
- When I try to update data from the database it display Conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string. "Am using

datetimepicker"`
 - 
**List item**
---------**

Comment: a quick try you can do is save the excel file as .CSV and then try to bulk insert the data into SQL server (keeping column names as same data-types)

Comment: Hi junketsu, thanks for the ideal. when I save the data as csv and I import it to sql server 2014, some data that is character change to something like this '34526'

Comment: ok you will have to QA that specific row. Since you save data as CSV format. Open it with Notepad++ (this is a free program and much better than Notepad). Then look at that specific trouble row and see data is how it is in excel version. if that is the case you can weed out that its a CSV conversion issue. Insert only that single row into SQL server and see how it appears. If its different you know its a varchar/nvarchar issue on handeling that specific character. Issue has to be in either of those 2 steps.